# Bash source + npm script function not exported but variable is

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

Can someone explain the difference in output when running the following on mac vs linux.

test.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

testFunc(){
    echo "test function";
}

export -f testFunc;

export testVar="test variable";
```

package.json

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "setup": "echo $testVar && testFunc"
    }
}
```

Command in terminal

```bsh
source ./test.sh; npm run setup
```

Output on mac Terminal app running bash

```bsh
> echo $testVar && testFunc

"test variable"
"test function"
```

Output on linux WSL ubuntu running bash

```bsh
> echo $testVar && testFunc

"test variable"
sh: 1: testFunc: not found
```

----- Edit

You can get around the differences by setting then unsetting the npm default shell.

```bsh
npm config set script-shell "/bin/bash"; source ./test.sh; npm run setup; npm config delete script-shell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can deduce from the error message, `npm-run` uses `/bin/sh` by default, as discussed [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script).

In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is the Almquist `dash` shell, which doesn't recognize exported functions. On Mac it's likely `bash` running in `sh` compatibility mode - which apparently does.

I don't really know anything about npm, however it should be possible to configure it to use `/bin/bash` via `npm config set script-shell` - I don't know enough to know whether that's advisable, or whether you would be better off finding a different way to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: You're correct, dash/bash differences is where my issue lay.